# How to setup a forward proxy and a reverse proxy on the same server using Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache, http-proxy

I have an application that acts as both a HTTP server as well as a HTTP client.  For security reasons, the application runs on a server on a protected/internal network.  I would like to setup a HTTP proxy that acts as an external interface for external parties to access the application.

For external HTTP clients to access my application, I would like to have a reverse proxy to handle such scenarios.

For HTTP request from my application to external parties, I would like to have a forward proxy to ensure my proper external URL's are sent to the external parties.

Question:  Can Apache HTTPD proxy be configured to run a both a forward proxy and reverse proxy at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (from my reading of the docs) is No.

The forward proxy is activated using the `ProxyRequests` directive

A reverse proxy is activated using the `ProxyPass` directive.
The [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) docs state

> The ProxyRequests directive should
>   usually be set off when using
>   ProxyPass.

I think if you enable both on the same server, there will be a possible clash in your Allow, Deny settings for IPs etc